# I cant read file with python on linux mint

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, linux-mint

Im writing the telegram bot on python using aiogram. So...

I just need to open a file via python on linux mint but I JUST CANT DO IT. File have some data inside but I always receive THE EMPTY. I cant understand why...

Maybe its my code's fault so thats the code:

```
    text = message.text
    refer = text.split() if len(text.split()) > 1 else None
    
    if refer:
        with open('referals_admins', 'r') as referals:
            for el in referals.readlines():
                if el.split(':')[0] == refer:
                    print(f'{refer}:{int(el.split()[1]) + 1}', file=referals)
```

I checked the opening file on new project and it isnt working too...

I checked the happening in debugger and saw that I RECEIVE THE RIGHT DATA, but on the next row its [] again.

I new to linux so mb I dont know some features of opening files? idk, pls help me.

Im using Linux Mint 21.1

Comment: `if el.split(':')[0] == refer:` - your `refer` is a list here, so perhaps you meant to use `if el.split(':')[0] in refer:` instead?

Comment: Good addition, thanks, I forgot about it... But the problem in another: I cant correctly open the 'referals_admins' file. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem description. If the file cannot be opened you should be getting some kind of exception with more information being thrown. But later on your description claims that the file can be opened but doesn't have the right data?

Comment: Sorry... I will describe in a little more detail. I opened the file but the result of readlines() is incorrect (empty [ ] ) but I have 50 (!) rows with data there in file. I tried to check the info in the debugger and saw that on `with open('referals_admins', 'r') as referals:` readlines() works correctly but on the next row `for el in referals.readlines():` the result is empty...

Comment: Can you post a short example of your data (`message`  and some of the file contents)? What do you mean the result is empty? If you try printing `el` it should work, so what part is empty?